# How to get Current object from TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF treeView which has ControlTemplate which show every node of treeView consisting of two elements : Image + Textbox. When I change TextBox treeView element not select. But I want to get Selected class in TextChanged event of TextBox. How can I get class to which current textBox Bound in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Bind textbox's `IsFocused` property to treeviewitems's `IsSelected` property

```
<TextBox IsFocused = {Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Mode="OneWayToSource"} />
```

Else Add a trigger to the textbox such that whenever the `IsFocused` property is set to true, the corresponding treeviewitem's `IsSelected` property is also set true.